# Windows 8 UI - Split applications in 50:50 ratio of screen width

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Modern UI Apps - How to Snap at center](https://superuser.com/questions/494326/windows-8-modern-ui-apps-how-to-snap-at-center)

Windows 8 provides a way to "dock" applications on either the left or right side of the screen, so they take only 20 percent of the width. Thus, another app can take the other 80 percent and a side-by-side use is possible.

Is it possible to use a 50:50 ratio instead of a 80:20?

Comment: To clarify, I assume you are asking about Metro app docking. Desktop apps can be docked 50/50 with Windows key + Left/Right arrow, just like in Windows 7.

Comment: Pretty much the same thing is also discussed in [Is there a way to splitscreen Metro apps in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/496563/is-there-a-way-to-splitscreen-metro-apps-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use apps in 50/50 split-screen mode. One app will always be snapped to the side of your screen, while the other app will take up the majority of your screen.

Source: [Howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/127756/how-to-run-two-windows-8-apps-at-the-same-time-with-the-snap-feature/)

Answer (score 2):

The standard 1366x768 resolution can be snapped (split) to 1024x768 + 320x768, or the opposite. (the missing 22 pixels are the width of the grip). Snap is keyboard controlled with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (that's a period by the way). This is the only supported snap.

If your resolution varies, the ratios remains the same. SnapView, by the way differentiates Windows 8 from other tablets in that it allows for more than one mobile UI application to have active threads at one time.

> My explanation: Windows is likely to support only snap for a long time, too. The reason I say that is from a development perspective, applications are required, in order to pass Store certification, to support full screen and snap layout. 50x50 layout would require yet another application requirement for developers to meet - and that would take a considerable reword for the apps in the store already and those pending and those nearing completion. 50x50 isn't currently supported. 50x50 won't like be supported anytime soon either.